# Converting from qmake to cmake, how do I find libraries in the same way?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qmake

in qmake I can have something like this:

```
LIBS += -lopengl32 \
    -lglu32
```

This will automatically find and link the OpenGL and GLU with my application. How can I do the same in cmake? Is it as simple as:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} opengl32 glu32)
```

If so, how does cmake know where to find these libraries? Is there a way to do this that involves a `find_libraries` call instead? The above (if it works), would give me anxiety.

Comment: A CMake command `target_link_libraries` simply passes the library name to the linker. In its turn, the linker searches libraries in *predefined* locations and ones added by `link_directories` command. This functionality seems to be very similar to one provided by `LIBS` in QMake, doesn't it? A CMake command `find_package` provides more flexible way for search **some** libraries. This way is cross-platform, and works even for libraries installed into custom (user-defined) location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

#### About the sample you provided:

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} opengl32 glu32)
```

In this case, when you just list libraries to be linked against, CMake will just pass them to the linker, without any additional work; it is the linker, who must find them.

#### About the CMake way of including libraries:

However, CMake may help you much much more. Pls take a look at the following code snippet, that represents the preferred way of finding libraries in CMake:

```
#NOTE: this is a complete & working CMakeLists.txt

project(my_opengl_program)

set(TARGET_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(TARGET_SOURCES my_opengl_program.cpp my_opengl_program.h)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${TARGET_SOURCES})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} OpenGL::GL OpenGL::GLU)
```

Instead of using `find_library` directly, use `find_package`. It will find the libraries you need (by employing `find_library` internally) and set various helpful variables for you.

Also, most of the packages will also define so-called import libraries, `OpenGL::GL` and `OpenGL::GLU` in your case, that can be used for linking. The wonderful thing about linking against the *CMake targets* is that your executable will inherit all relevant compile/link requirements from the target used for linking. Of course, "import libraries" are also CMake targets :)

Please note that there are *NO* additional compile/link options, include directories, compile definitions, etc... for your executable. Everything that is necessary is inherited from `OpenGL::GL` and `OpenGL::GLU`.

CMake also provides packages for [many standard libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) (scroll down to "Find Modules").

#### About searching for libraries

You can always use `find_library` directly, and in that case, it is your responsibility to take care of all requirements the library imposes.

Determining the places to search for libraries may be quite complex, and is driven by various `CMake` variables, as well as parameters passed to `find_library`. In the simplest case, when no related `CMAKE_*` variables are changed, and when the find_library is called with basic syntax, like:

```
find_library(GL_LIB opengl32)
fund_library(GLU_LIB glu32)
```

Search for `openGL32` and `glu32` will be controlled by `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH` CMake variables.

In the end, here is the complete documentation for [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html), [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package),  [cmake supported libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) (scroll down to "Find Modules"), [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries)

#### [update]

#### find_library vs find_package

The question was raised about the difference between `find_library` and `find_package`.

Briefly, these two commands do not "compete" but rather "complement" each other. One may think about `find_library` as a low-level interface for including libraries. In this context, `find_package` would be a much higher interface, that is easier to use. On the other hand, `find_package` requires additional support from the library maintainers, or from the CMake directly.

Digging a little deeper into the problem:

Suppose that some library is introduced using
`find_library (SOME_OTHER_LIB some_other_lib_name)`. If the lib was found, the variable `SOME_OTHER_LIB` will contain the path to the library, which is enough for linking, using `target_link_libraries`.

But to really use the library, sources need to include `SOME_OTHER_LIB` specific headers, i.e. another `find_path(...)` needs to be introduced, to locate headers, followed by `target_include_directories(...)`. Also, compile options required by the library also need to be extracted somehow, and introduced using `target_compile_options(...)`

Of course, if the SOME_OTHER_LIB is used on more than one place, all `target_include_directories`, `target_compile_options`, and `target_link_libraries` must be used all over.

The same process must be repeated for every foreign library that is used.

One can quickly spot the pattern, and this is exactly where `find_package` becomes handy. All that low-level work is hidden from the end-user (i.e. developer using CMake), and she/he is presented with a clean and unified interface. The downside is that `find_package` requires a "kind of driver" that will "drive" the process of including the foreign library. All libraries that are directly supported by CMake may be found on [cmake-modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) (scroll down to  "Find Modules").

The icing on the cake, almost all find modules also create so-called "import libraries" (`OpenGL::GL` and `OpenGL::GLU` in your case) that are cmake targets holding all requirements of the 3rd party library. All those data are inherited by just linking against the import library, making the code much cleaner.

Unfortunately, there are no "enforcements" about the naming of created import libraries (just guidelines), so the only solution is to check the documentation. For `OpenGL` module, it can be found on [FindOpenGL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html) page.

Comment: This is a fantastic breakdown! Thank you so much. I guess my question is then, conceptually, what distinguishes a package from a library? How would I know that OpenGL is something that can be found as a package on my system? How would I then know that it has `OpenGL::GL` and `OpenGL::GLU` as sub-libraries?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, but better late than never :) I have updated the answer to include the questions you raised in the comment. Cheers!